# Remove a Text in the Anchor Tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code here:

```
<a href="#"><i class="flaticon-basket9"></i> addtobasket</a>
```

I want remove the "addtobasket" text .

Trying using jquery code:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').text(' ');
    })
```

but that code removed `<i>` tag also.just want to remove the text.

the "addtobasket" text may change and that not constant

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over the nodes within the anchor, checking for a matching text node:

```
$('a').contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove('');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r2u9x1s8/)**

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$('a').contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

---

You can also use:

```
$('a i').prop('nextSibling').value = '';
```

Comment: bravo,that's work.can you please add more detail about your code.

Comment: If you see what I'm doing you should see why your example doesn't work. It wasn't just the `.text()` / `.remove()` thing.

Comment: I checked with remove() and working, anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("a").html($('a').children());
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($('a>span').html());
  $('a>span').html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><i class="flaticon-basket9"></i> <span>addtobasket</span></a>
```